# Why are "thankyous" depreciated on EE.SE?

Tags: discussion

When I started out on EE.SE I asked a couple of questions with the "Thanks for help" line at the end because I wanted to express my genuine appreciation for people taking the time to answer my questions - only to find after 5 minutes people snagging it off.

Could I ask why this is? For the sake of appreciation and sacrificing one line, it seems pointless (except for those looking to earn the "editor" badge).

Comment: Heavy fam, what's with the downvotes?

Comment: Downvote on meta has a different meaning than on the main board.  It only means disagreement.  It doesn't mean that the post is sub-standard in some way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are people, not being me, who think extra lines like that cause clutter.

I see the point of "Hello, ..." and "I have a very specific problem..." being removed, though the latter seems to be invulnerable to such scrutiny the last months. Those initial lines with *no information* make the overview/excerpt system pointless.

Personally, however, I do not see the point of removing final thanks.
Maybe some international (to me) element finds it clutter through inherent societal apathy. Whatever it be, someone decided to make it a rule (officially), for some reason, that such ends also do not belong.